# Find the number of permutations in $S_n$ containing fixed elements in one cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> Find the number of permutations in $S_n$ such as 1 and 2 belong to one cycle.

Comment: Do you mean the number of permutations with the cycle (transposition) $(1, 2)$? Or do you mean such that $1, 2$ are both in the same cycle, of whatever length?

Comment: I mean that they belong to cycle of arbitrary length, not only transposition.

Comment: Well, I've come to $\frac{1}{2}$ as an answer, so it's only to check if I haven't miscalculated something.

Comment: You mean $\frac{n!}{2}$, right ?

Comment: @Doc, yes, and $\frac{1}{2}$ is just a relative number.

Comment: Yep, it's the probability of picking such a cycle.  How does your argument go?  I've been looking at the bijection $\sigma \to (1,2)\sigma$.

Comment: @Doc, I've fixed 1 and started to gather permutations with property that 1 and 2 do not belong to one cycle. First, there are $(n-1)!$ permutations such as 1 doesn't belong to any cycle. Then, there are $(n-2)!(n-2)$ permutations like (1x)(...). Then, there are $(n-3)!(n-3)(n-2)$ permutations like (1xy)(...). When we sum all such permutations, we get $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-2)!k = \frac{(n-2)!(n-1)n}{2} = \frac{n!}{2}$.

I like your approach, though.

Comment: @tenpercent: On this page, questions containing only a problem statement are not recieved well, because it looks like you didn't do any own work on it (which of course is not the case here). To avoid that the question gets closed, you should add your thoughts on this problem (which you gave in the comment above) to your question.

Comment: @tenpercent, azimut makes a really good point here.  It's obvious from the exchange of comments that not only have you put a great deal of thought into the problem but that you have some really good math skills.  You definitely want to reflect this in your question!  You wouldn't believe what we encounter on this board, and you definitely don't want to be lumped together with the sort of people who come on here and post questions without making the slightest effort to solve them.

Comment: Thank you, guys, I'll do better next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $X \subseteq S_n$ be the set of all permutations having $1$ and $2$ in separate cycles and $Y \subseteq S_n$ the set of all permutations having $1$ and $2$ in the same cycle.

Show that the mapping $f : X \to Y$ which "glues together" the two cycles containing $1$ and $2$ (cycles written down such that they start with $1$ and $2$, resp.) is a bijection.

Example in $S_7$:
$$f((1,7,4)(2,6)(3,5)) = (1,7,4,2,6)(3,5).$$

**Remark**

As pointed out by P.. below, the mapping rule of $f$ can be written as
$$
\sigma \mapsto (1,2)\sigma
$$

Comment: Nice! This function can be written explicitly as $f(\sigma)=(1,2)\sigma$ as Doc noted in the comments!

Comment: @P..: Thanks, that's really a nice observation! I didn't notice that it is the same. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

We can also compute this by direct enumeration. Suppose we ask about the probability that a random subset $Q$ containing $m$ elements ends up on the same cycle in a permutation of $n$ elements. If the $m$ elements are on a cycle of length $r\ge m$ then we need to choose the remaining $r-m$ elements and interleave the elements of $Q$ with these extra elements. This gives $$\sum_{r=m}^n {n-m\choose r-m} \frac{r!}{r} (n-r)!
= \sum_{r=0}^{n-m} {n-m\choose r} (r+m-1)! (n-m-r)!$$

Observe that when we multiply two exponential generating functions of the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that
$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} \sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
i.e. the product of the two generating functions is the generating function of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

Now in the present case we clearly have
$$A(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} (q+m-1)! \frac{z^q}{q!} 
= (m-1)! \sum_{q\ge 0} {q+m-1\choose q} z^q = \frac{(m-1)!}{(1-z)^m}.$$
Furthermore we have
$$B(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} q! \frac{z^q}{q!} = \sum_{q\ge 0} z^q = \frac{1}{1-z}.$$
It follows that the sum is given by
$$(n-m)! [z^{n-m}] A(z) B(z)
= (n-m)! [z^{n-m}] \frac{(m-1)!}{(1-z)^{m+1}}\\
= (n-m)! (m-1)! {n-m+m\choose n-m} = (m-1)! \frac{n!}{m!} = \frac{n!}{m}.$$
Therefore the desired probability is
$$\frac{1}{n!}  \frac{n!}{m} = \frac{1}{m}.$$

This can also be done using exponential generating functions as shown at this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics).